# Mongodb Driver: missing delimiting slash between hosts and options

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I copied codes from [MONGODB NODE.JS DRIVER 2.2](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/authenticating/) and modified a little.

```
// connect to mongodb
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
f = require('util').format;

var user = encodeURIComponent('admin'),
password = encodeURIComponent('123456'),
authMechanism = 'DEFAULT',
authSource = 'admin';

// connection url
var url = f('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:27017?authMechanism=%s&authSource=%s',
user, password, authMechanism, authSource);

var db = null;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) { //Here is line 20!
    if(err) { 
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err); 
    }
    else {  
        console.log('Connection established to', url);
        db = database // once connected, assign the connection to the global variable 
    }
})
```

However, I met an odd error.

```
Error: missing delimiting slash between hosts and options.
at module.exports (/home/lixing/Dropbox/thesis/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:37:11)
at connect (/home/lixing/Dropbox/thesis/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:289:16)
at Function.MongoClient.connect (/home/lixing/Dropbox/thesis/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:113:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lixing/Dropbox/thesis/server.js:20:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

It is mentioned in the console that there is something wrong in MongoClient.connect.

However, I couldn't fix this problem. Is it a bug or my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are missing a `/` between the port number and the options.

`mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=%s&authSource=%s`

More information about connection strings: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: I hate to ask but since it's the correct answer can you upvote?

Comment: Actually, I've upvoted, but it won't be displayed because my rep is less than 15.

Comment: as an addition to this comment, make sure that username/password are uriEncoded otherwise you might get the same error and auth won't work